# How to get redirection page

Tags: java, wicket

I have two page:

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation(Roles.ADMIN)
public class AdminPage extends BasePage {
...

@AuthorizeInstantiation(Roles.USER)
public class UserPage extends BasePage {
...
```

when there isnt any user logged in then he is redirected to login page. Is there some option how to get redirection page ? So if user go to admin page then login page println admin page. If user go to user page then login page println user page and when user go just login page then login page println null

UPDATE:

strategy when you go to protected page

```
    getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(LoginPage.class);
```

what isnt clear enought ? when user want to get to UserPage or AdminPage he is regirected to LoginPage. And I want to println in loginPage which page it was

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it:

I create unauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener:

```
    getSecuritySettings().setUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener(
            new IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener() {
                public void onUnauthorizedInstantiation(final Component component) {
                    if (component instanceof Page) {
                        // Redirect to index
                        if (component instanceof AdminPage) {
                            redirectionPage = ((AdminPage) component);
                        } else if (component instanceof BalancerPage) {
                            redirectionPage = ((UserPage) component);
                        }
                        throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(LoginPage.class);
                        // Or you can just throw the original UnauthorizedInstantiationException
                    } else {
                        component.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

and setting variable in appliaction.

Then just in login page I call `Application.getRedirectionPage()` so I know which page it was

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for but you could take a look at

```
RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException.InterceptData.get();
```

InterceptData holds some information about the page that triggered redirection.

Comment: hm I dont see this construction in wicket 1.5+

Answer (score 0):

You have not described how you do the redirect to the login page. I guess you implement an IAuthorizationStrategy and IUnauthorizedComponentInstantiationListener? In you implementation of onUnauthorizedInstantiation(), you could check which annotation is present on the passed in Component (aka, your page) and depending on this pass a parameter to the login page.

Comment: soryy updated I do this throught         getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(LoginPage.class);